# How do I increase performance of PyEnchant for spelling correction?

Tags: python, spelling, pyenchant

Consider there is a big list of words and PyEnchant spelling correction has to be performed on every single word in this list. I use a custom dictionary for spelling correction which gets updated over time. As I have seen, Spelling correction process takes a very long time, is there any feasible/optimal solution to reduce the processing time ?